# My Animation involving a GravitySimulation won't animate

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The container widget which is being animated stays at the starting point of the animation ie. the animation doesn't start, but if a single widget is used instead of a list of widgets like the `particles` list I made then the animation works fine.
Why is this so and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(PhysicsAnimation());

class PhysicsAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  _PhysicsAnimation createState() => _PhysicsAnimation();
}

class _PhysicsAnimation extends State<PhysicsAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  AnimationController controller;
  GravitySimulation simulation;
  List<Widget> particles=[];
  bool isLoad=true;

  Random random=new Random();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    simulation = GravitySimulation(
      100, // acceleration
      0.0, // starting point
      2000.0, // end point
      5, // starting velocity
    );


    controller =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, upperBound: 800)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    controller.animateWith(simulation);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (isLoad) {
     for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
      particles.add(Positioned(
          left: 50+random.nextDouble()*100,
          top: controller.value,
          height: 10,
          width: 10,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          )));}
   }
    isLoad=false;
      return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
          children:

            particles

      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been awhile, but did you managed to solve this?  I think you need to reset isLoad in your setState and clear the particles list before adding more particles.

```
controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, upperBound: 800)
  ..addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      **isLoad = true;**
    });
  });
```

...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (isLoad) {
  **particles.clear();**
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    particles.add(Positioned(
        left: 50 + random.nextDouble() * 500,
        top: controller.value,
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
        )));
  }
}
isLoad = false;
return Stack(children: particles);
```

}